# GWT 2.7 Supported Browser Version

Tags: gwt, browser

Is anybody knows what are the supported browser version for GWT 2.7? In GWT official page they listed [link](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_GettingStarted.html#Browsers_and_Servers) , but i dont no for which GWT version this browser will support.Any help?

Comment: As the link says. the latest version of GWT.

Comment: then what are the browser version GWT 2.7 will support? they link says for GWT 2.8 right?

Comment: No the latest version is 2.7 as you can see in the [release notes](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_Current)

Comment: thanks jens for your reply..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the GWT Official page [link](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_GettingStarted.html#Browsers_and_Servers)..

**GWT 2.7 supports the following browsers:**

- Firefox
- Internet Explorer 8, 9, 10, 11
- Safari 5, 6
- Chromium and Google Chrome
- Opera latest version